How to filter out rows where only one instance of spesific value exists
Dataset simplified:
Id <- c(1,1,1,2,3,3,4,5,5)
Values <- c(50, 60, 45, 55, 50, 90, 80, 50 40)
df <- data.frame(Id, Values)

Now I want to filter out rows where there is only one instance of spesific Id (in this case 2 and 4). So expected result should be something like this:
Id Values
1 50
1 60
1 45
3 50
3 90
5 50
5 40

I am new with R and can't figure out how to filter this. Thank you for the help in advance :)

here is one way: df |> filter(n() > 1, .by = Id)
This takes df (btw, you missed the last comma in values) and filters only Ids that appear more than once (using the n() to count, and .by to specify that it's by each id)
Please note that this approach is using dplyr, and more broadly, the tidyverse syntax, I recommend installing the tidyverse and get familiar with its syntax. good luck!
install.packages('tidyverse') to do so, and then library(tidyverse)

Thank you very much! Yes I am already using tidyverse and trying to learn how to use it :)
